# Update view when make changes in another view Angular

Tags: angularjs

I have one controller per view. I want to after the user makes click on a button that add an element to the database, then that element appear in the other view.

I try to use $emit and $on, but the problem is that I have one controller in each view, the controllers are not in the same view.

Controller that broadcast:

```
angular.module('clientApp')
.controller('MovieViewCtrl',[ '$scope', '$rootScope' ,'$routeParams','$location' ,'Movie', 'Like', 'auth', function ( $scope, rootScope ,$routeParams,$location ,Movie, Like, auth) {

//Another code here....

Like.post($scope.like).then(function(){
        $rootScope.$broadcast('newLike', 'new like was added');
        $location.path('/movie/' + $routeParams.id)
});
```

Controller that receive:

```
angular.module('clientApp')

  .controller('MainCtrl'['$scope','$rootScope','Movie','Like','$location',

  function ($scope,$rootScope,$routeParams,Movie,Like,$location) {


   $rootScope.$on('newLike', function (event, arg) {
     $scope.receiver = 'got your ' + arg;
     console.log($scope.receiver);
     $scope.likes = Like.getList({limit:5}).$object;
   });
  }
]);
```

Comment: You can use `$rootScope.$broadcast` to reach all current scopes. You could also share state in a service / factory used in each controller

Comment: Use `service`, One of it's purpose is to serve values between controllers.

Comment: @Phil I edited my question with the code that use $rootScope but don't work.

Comment: Well yeah, you broadcast "newLike" but listen for "newElement"

Comment: @Phil yes, my bad. I edited with "newLike" but is not working.

Comment: Do the `console.log` lines work as expected? You could always put the new `like` as the event data instead of the string `"new like was added"` instead of querying for it from the server

Comment: @Phil No, the `console.log` is not working. Is like it never enters there. Yes you are right on sending the `like` as data. 

**Edit** I change the msg to the like, and now the  `console.log` is working but in the view that broadcast, not in the one that receive.

Comment: Not sure what you mean there, I don't see any `console.log` in the broadcaster

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115062/discussion-between-joseph-and-phil).